# Facebook-Login with ReactNative not returning expected data

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I log in my user with the FBSDK wrapper I use:

```
LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(result => {

  // find user information here if accepted

});
```

I do find the email address in the response and also the users photoURL. However, I really need the first name and last name separately. I just get a property called `displayName` back that has both first name and last name in one string.

I dont want to do some hacky things like splitting at the first space of the string to get the first name since it wont always work (the user could have a middlename?).

Facebook does specify that you get a field called `first_name` & `last_name` back as per [the official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-public_profile).

Anyone know how I can reliably fetch the users first and last name?

Thanks!

Comment: @luschn Sorry if I am a bit slow on this one, but I thought specifying `.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile'])` would return me those values by default?

Comment: i created an answer, to make it more clear. by default, you only get default values like id and displayName. if you want more fields, you need to ask for them (in a separate api request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask for the fields you want to get, or you will only get default ones. For example, you can get the first_name and last_name fields with this API call:

```
const infoRequest = new GraphRequest('/me', {
    parameters: {
        fields: {
            string: 'first_name,last_name'
        }
    }
}, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
    } else {
        console.log('Success fetching data: ' + result.toString());
    }
});
new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start();
```

Comment: Thank you!! I dont know why I did not understand that you have to do a new request.